# MongoDB AggregateArgs missing

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am wondering why I can't do `var args = new AggregateArgs();` AggregateArgs is missing. I am using `Mongodb.Driver`
Asp.net core 2.2 and mongodb driver 2.7.3

Comment: Answer posting an answer, not editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the API shows AggregateArgs class it's not available in the new version of the c# driver. It is in the legacy version...